# How to scale data in special range [0.9 1.1]?

Tags: image, algorithm, matlab, image-processing

I have a raw data which range is from `16399` to `64678`. I want to 
rescaled the data in a given range [1-`alpha`, 1+`alpha`], where `alpha` is given. The rescaled data need to maintain the properties of the data: "non-linear, and slowly-varying". I made a code to do it. However, the range does not in range [0.9 1.1] (alpha=0.1). The current result range in [0.4 1.5]. Could you help me to provide the way to fix it? Thank all

[image]
This is my code and [data](https://www.dropbox.com/s/cbyutczg7guvnop/original_data.mat?dl=0)

```
load original_data.mat;
data=double(data);
X_data=data(:,1);
Y_data=data(:,2);
%% Scale in range [0.9 1.1]
mid_range=(min(data(:))+max(data(:)))/2;
X_data_scale=X_data./mid_range;
Y_data_scale=Y_data./mid_range;
%% Plot
subplot(221);plot(X_data);title('Original X data');grid on
subplot(222);plot(X_data_scale);title('Scale X data');grid on
subplot(223);plot(Y_data);title('Original Y data');grid on
subplot(224);plot(Y_data_scale);title('Scale Y data');grid on
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about regular min/max normalization:

```
   in - min(in)        out - min(out)
----------------- = --------------------
max(in) - min(in)    max(out) - min(out)
```

solving for `out` you get:

```
% in is x, out is xx
load data
x = data(:,1);
xx = (x - min(x)) * (1.1 - 0.9) / (max(x) - min(x)) + 0.9;
subplot(121), plot(x)
subplot(122), plot(xx)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank Amro. It is right. I got it. I just ask one more thing: Do you know how can I create the raw data as above properties: non-linear and slowly variation. If not, it is fine. I accepted your ans

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question?

Comment: Yes, the above raw data (got from other website) is called Intensity non-uniformity fields (INU) or bias field. These fields are not linear, but are slowly-varying fields of a complex shape. Based on that defination, I want to create my own data as shown in above.

Comment: so you want to generate random data that looks like that shape in the plot? hmm, I dont know...

Comment: Yes. Thank for above ans. It is really helpful

Comment: just for fun, I remember reading some posts on WolframAplha blog about making formulas for all kinds of curves: http://blog.wolframalpha.com/2013/07/18/even-more-formulas-for-everything-from-filled-algebraic-curves-to-the-twitter-bird-the-american-flag-chocolate-easter-bunnies-and-the-superman-solid/. pretty cool stuff :)